# Use JavaScript DataTable with getCookie and SetCookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, datatable

I want to remove the hard-coded values from "order" and get those values from "getCookie" function.  How can I do this?  Whenever I click on a table column, it gets sorted.  I want to store that sorting order by setCookie function.  When the page refreshes, I want to get that sorting order from getCookie function.  Thanks.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        let sortValue = getCookie("releaseTicketSort")
        var oTable = $('#allTicketsTable').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 5,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "fixedHeader": true,
            "lengthMenu": [ [5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
            "order": [[2, 'asc']],

            columnDefs: [
                { width: 150, targets: 5 },
                { className: "dt-center", targets: 5}
            ],

            fnDrawCallback: function (settings){
                console.log(settings.oSavedState.order)
                var orderVec = settings.oSavedState.order
                setCookie("releaseTicketSort", orderVec, exp=1000)
                getCookie("releaseTicketSort")
            }
        });
    });

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name) return unescape(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but it sounds like you want the sort order of a table to be re-applied to the table after the user has left the page and then returned to it later. If that is correct, I think using local storage instead of cookies is a better approach. This is discussed in relation to DataTables [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave).

Comment: And if you are looking to save only specific aspects of the overall state (e.g. _only_ the sorting) then [stateSaveCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) and/or `stateLoadCallback` may be a better fit.

Comment: Hi Andrew, that's correct.  Let's say that I have Columns A, B, C, D in my table.  If I sort the  table on Column C and leave the page and come back, the table should look the same - being sorted on C.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cookies, I would suggest using the state-saving functions built into DataTables (assuming you are using DataTables v1.10 or later).

For your scenario where you *only* want to save the state of sorting between page loads (but not paging, and not filtering), then the [`stateSaveParams`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveParams) option is probably the simplest approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  
    stateSave: true,
    
    stateSaveParams: function (settings, data) {
      data.start = 0;
      data.search.search = '';
    }

  } );
  
} );
```

The above options cause all the table's state data to be stored in your browser's local storage. A typical entry will contain data in the following structure:

```json
{
    "time": 1651180700425,
    "start": 0,
    "length": 10,
    "order": [
        [0, "asc"]
    ],
    "search": {
        "search": "",
        "smart": true,
        "regex": false,
        "caseInsensitive": true
    },
    "columns": [{
        "visible": true,
        "search": {
            "search": "",
            "smart": true,
            "regex": false,
            "caseInsensitive": true
        }
    }, 
        . . . 
    {
        "visible": true,
        "search": {
            "search": "",
            "smart": true,
            "regex": false,
            "caseInsensitive": true
        }
    }]
}
```

The `stateSaveParams` option will then override the `start` and `search.search` values so those are saved as their default values (first page, and no search term) instead of whatever values the user may have provided:

```
stateSaveParams: function (settings, data) {
  data.start = 0;
  data.search.search = '';
}
```

Nothing else is altered - including the sorting values. This saved data is automatically retrieved from local storage by DataTables, because of the `stateSave: true` option.

So, you don't need to explicitly save the sorting data - you only need to explicitly "unsave" the other options that you don't actually want to preserve/restore.

Background and reference: More about [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).